# Export DataTable to Excel with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, export, epplus

I want to export a data table to an Excel file with EPPlus. That data table has a property with int type, so I want the same format in the Excel file.

Does anyone know way to export a DataTable like this to Excel?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
  ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Accounts");
  ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
  pck.Save();
}
```

That should do the trick for you. If your fields are defined as int EPPlus will properly cast the columns into a number or float.

Comment: How to format headers of datatable while exporting ??

Comment: Yes. this is working fine. But when the datatable contains rows in lakhs. This one is not working.

Comment: Maybe you should open a question for that specific case then?

Comment: The headers will be included @AbhinavRastogi

Comment: using OfficeOpenXml; (required for reference to ExcelPackage/ExcelWorksheet)

Comment: Clean approach. Thanks!

Comment: This is 9 years old and still helps people. SO amazes me again and again. @AshokanSivapragasam thank you for reminding me of this!

Answer (score 21):

and if you want to download in browser response

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Logs.xlsx", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Logs");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);                 
    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    pck.SaveAs(ms);
    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);                          
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! No need to urlencode "Logs.xlsx" :)

Answer (score 5):

For downloading excelsheet in browser use `HttpContext.Current.Response` instead of `Response` otherwise you will get *`Response is not available in this context.`* error.Here is my code

```
public void ExporttoExcel(DataTable table, string filename)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridData.xlsx");


    using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        pack.SaveAs(ms);
        ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream); 
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
```

Comment: For anyone getting 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current':  To get a reference to HttpContext.Current you need replace

HttpContext.Current
with

System.Web.HttpContext.Current  
                             
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431820/system-web-httpcontextbase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-current-mvc-4-wi

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet to export DataSet to Excel:

```
    private static void DataSetToExcel(DataSet dataSet, string filePath)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
            {
                ExcelWorksheet workSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dataTable.TableName);
                workSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
            }

            pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(filePath));
        }
    }
```

And using statements:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Foreword

<sup>With v5, EPPlus switched to a paid-for licensing model for commercial use. To use v5 in a non-commercial setting you need to put this static line of code somewhere that will run:</sup>

```
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
```

<sup>If you're using it commercially, your company can obtain a license or use v4.5.3.3 (it does work in netcore/net5) which was the last version that can be used fee-free commercially</sup>

The following code works on 4.5.3.3

## C#

DataTable to Excel, using column names as excel headers.

It also loops over the table afterwards and sets any DateTime columns so that they show in Excel as a date, not a number like 45123

```
        DataTable dt = ...;
        string sheetName = ...;
        string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

        using var p = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, PrintHeaders: true);
        for (int c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            if (dt.Columns[c].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                ws.Column(c + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = dateFormat;
            }
        }
```

If you're using this in e.g. an API controller you can use the following to return it as a downloading file:

```
    string fileName = ...;  //without extension

    return File(p.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName + ".xlsx");
```

Be aware of the scope of the `using`! It's C#8 syntax and lives until the end of the block it's declared in

## VB.NET

Same as above, but in VB:

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = ...
    Dim sheetName As String = ...
    Dim dateFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    Using p As New ExcelPackage()
        Dim ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName)
        ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, PrintHeaders:=True)

        For c As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1

            If dt.Columns(c).DataType Is GetType(Date) Then
                ws.Column(c + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = dateFormat
            End If
        Next
    End Using
```

And for the download, **it must be placed inside the using block**

```
    Dim fileName As String = ...  'without extension
    Return File(p.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName & ".xlsx")
```