# System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' MVC 4 with Elmah Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC 4 project, which is using Elmah for catching any unhandled exceptions.  This works great in most situations.

However I've found that for a controller method that is called using a JQuery Ajax call, I can't get the current Context.

For example in my controller method that returns the JsonResult I have this test code;

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("This is a test");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(e));
}
```

The

> HttpContext.Current

is causing the following error;

> 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for
>   'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I get around this problem ?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To get a reference to HttpContext.Current you need replace

```
HttpContext.Current
```

with

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current
```

This is because Controller class defines a property named HttpContext that is defined as

```
public HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; }
```

HttpContext on Controller class returns HttpContextBase which does not have a Current property.

Hence you need to properly resolve the namespace here.

Comment: I tried that which is fine if I'm catching the exception, but still Unhandled exceptions don't appear to be logged ?

Comment: @Tommo1977 i think, you might be missing proper elmah configuration, not sure though

Comment: thank you, i used this way, `System.Web.HttpContext curContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148209/asp-net-identity-httpcontext-has-no-extension-method-for-getowincontext