# ASP.NET Identity - HttpContext has no extension method for GetOwinContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have downloaded, and successfully ran the ASP.NET Identity sample from here:
https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample

I am now in the middle of implementing the ASP.NET Identity framework in my project and have ran into a problem, that has driven me mad all day...

> `GetOwinContext()` does not exist as an extension method on my `HttpContext`

I am implementing the identity framework in class library. I have installed all the latest (pre-release version) of the Identity framework and everything - apart from this - is working fine.

I have tried implementing the same code as the same direct in my controller, and find the same problem.

I'm clearly missing a reference somewhere, though I have no idea what..!..

The code-block that is killing me is:

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

I have added references to the following - tried these both in my class library and also direct on the controller, none of them work for me...

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using System.Web;
```

... this is driving me up the wall....any idea?

**UPDATE**

I have checked the versions of Identity & OWIN in the sample, and I have made sure I have the same versions in my solution.

More so, if I search the object browser on the sample for `GetOwinContext` I can find the method, however when I search for it in my solution it is nowhere to be found... I must have some library out of date, but I can't find it!

Answer (score 765, accepted):

ARGH!

**I found it**... I didn't have an extra package, called `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`

Once i searched and installed this, it worked.

Now - i am not sure if i just missed everything, though found NO reference to such a library or package when going through various tutorials. It also didn't get installed when i installed all this Identity framework... Not sure if it were just me..

**EDIT**
Although it's in the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` assembly it is an extension method in the `System.Web` namespace, so you need to have the reference to the former, and be `using` the latter.

Comment: Thanks for figuring that one out: I'm using this tutorial http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project and it's a missing step

Comment: Seems it's in there now - either that or we both missed it before :)

Comment: Instead of running around aimlessly, installing random libraries and expecting tutorials to be reference documentation, one should rather [lookup the method in the actual reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270723), then follow the link [to its class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextextensions) (on the left). Then, it's right in front of you: `Assembly:  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (in Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll)`. Literally one click.

Comment: @tne - thank you for your comment... though I was hardly 'running around aimlessly' - i was following a tutorial from a trusted resource; from the asp.net site no-less. They didn't have that step in their tutorial (it's since been added) - also, the fact people are upvoting both this answer and the original Q also goes to indicate that I wasn't the only one with this issue.

Comment: @Darren, fair enough. (I do realize I could have worded that differently.)

Comment: Just for reference: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/2.1.0

Comment: You also need the `using System.Web;` statement

Comment: None of the receipts here did help me so far :(

Comment: Thanks for this!! I've probably been following the same tutorials as you and they don't always include everything you need!

Comment: This is _EXACTLY_ why I hate extension methods, having to have *just the right namespace* in your using statements

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin; i missed this one. GOD i have started to hate extension methods.

Comment: There seems to be a new wrinkle in the elusive `GetOwinContext()` extension method. The method, as defined in the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.Systemweb` assembly, as referenced above, is an extension of the `HttpContextBase` class. It appears that the new Controller in  `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc v6.0.0-rc1` new returns `HttpContext` instead of the `HttpContextBase`.

Comment: Referencing Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb didn't do it for me. I'm using Owin 3.0.1. 
What fixed it though was referencing System.Web.Http.Owin in the project references.

Comment: Makes rolling your own simple authentication seem like a great idea

Comment: Nice work, just need to find for "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" in nuget and install it. What a shame Microsoft tutorial itself didn't point that out.

Comment: Don't know if it was from updating this reference, but I had to change up my assignment a little bit to `var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;` (Current included where it wasn't there in the question).

Comment: @Ortund - yes, I think for web forms this is what you need to do, the one without seems to be for MVC

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Installing this Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package also solved my problem with my error "getowincontext is not a member of system.web.httpcontext" but I was getting a Nuget errors trying to install it To get it installed, I first changed my target .NET Framework to 4.5.1 or higher** and then Nuget installed Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb just fine (** My original project targeted .NET Framework 4.5.0 and Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb would not install for me on 4.5.0.)

Comment: Why is this so messy

Answer (score 185):

I believe you need to reference the current `HttpContext` if you are outside of the controller.  The MVC controllers have a base reference to the current context.  However, outside of that, you have to explicitly declare you want the current `HttpContext`

```
return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

As for it not showing up, a new MVC 5 project template using the code you show above (the `IAuthenticationManager`) has the following using statements at the top of the account controller:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using WebApplication2.Models;
```

Commenting out each one, it appears the `GetOwinContext()` is actually a part of the System.Web.Mvc assembly.

Comment: Been trying this and just can't find it. - the GetOwinContext() i mean.

Comment: @Darren - I played with the sample template a little bit and may have the assembly you are missing.  Looks like you will need to reference `System.Web.Mvc` from your class project. When commented out, that is what made `HttpContext.GetOwinContext()` become unknown (and not the `Microsoft.Owin.Security` assembly)

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work directly on a controller too - and again can't find it.

Comment: This tripped me up. There is a public property `HttpContext` on the `Controller` class, so if you inherit from that, `HttpContext.GetOwinContext()` works as expected. If you inherit from `ApiController` though, there is no such property. Therefore, `HttpContext` will refer to the class, which will require you to use `Current` to access an instance of the class. So if you copy/paste code from a Controller to an ApiController and wonder why it doesn't work, this is the answer for you.

Comment: "Current" was the gotcha for me

Comment: I have a Web Site not MVC and adding Current was enough to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 24):

After trial and error comparing the using statements of my controller and the Asp.Net Template controller

```
using System.Web;
```

Solved the problem for me.
You are also going to need to add:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

To use GetUserManager method.

Microsoft couldn't find a way to resolve this automatically with right click and resolve like other missing using statements?

Comment: This worked for me as well. I already had the Identity libraries, but it seems to need System.Web.

Comment: This has apparently been moving around a lot, both in assemblies and in namespaces. Makes it really painful with it being an extension method. I've updated all of my libraries and this answer reflects where it currently is.

Comment: ah, ye ol' dll hell in a new shape

Comment: Yes, sadly, extension methods can't be resolved automatically.

Answer (score 22):

In my case adding **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin** reference via nuget did the trick.

Comment: Yes, this did it for me on the current latest version.  The extension method is in this Package, which is _Assemby_ **System.Web.Http.Owin** and within the _Namespace_ **System.Net.Http**

Answer (score 17):

Just using

> HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()

did the trick in my case.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you installed the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`. Then add `System.Net.Http` namespace.

Comment: I had that one in too. Turns out there was another library NOT installed when the Identity stuff was installed.

Comment: @Darren Please add package name. Thank you

Comment: @SaturnTechnologies For me, the other package was Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb and namespace System.Web

Comment: I second WiSeeker. For me, this didn't help. Darren's suggestion to install `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` did the trick though.

Answer (score 14):

**For Devs getting this error in Web API Project -**

The GetOwinContext extension method is defined in `System.Web.Http.Owin` dll and one more package will be needed i.e. `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`. This package needs to be installed in your project from nuget.

[Link To Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin): OWIN Package Install Command -

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
```

[Link To System.web Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/) : Package Install Command -

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

In order to resolve this error you need to find why its occurring in your case. Please Cross check below points in your code -

1. You must have reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;`

   using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
2. Define `GetOwinContext()` Under `HttpContext.Current` as below -

   ```
    return _userManager1 ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
   ```

   OR

   ```
   return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
   ```

Complete Code Where GetOwinContext() is used -

```
 public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
 {
   get
   {
    return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
   }
    private set
    {
     _signInManager = value;
    }
  }
```

**Namespace's** I'm Using in Code File where GetOwinContext() Is used

```
using AngularJSAuthentication.API.Entities;
using AngularJSAuthentication.API.Models;
using HomeCinema.Common;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
```

I got this error while moving my code from my one project to another.

Answer (score 5):

**To get UserManager in API**

```
return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
```

where AppUserManager is the class that inherits from UserManager.

Answer (score 5):

Just install this package and your code will work:=>
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb -Version 2.1.0

Answer (score 4):

I had all the correct packages and usings, but had to built first before I could get `GetOwinContext()` to work.

Comment: How did you fix your build to make it works the first time?

Comment: @Nordes Sometimes VS fails to build in the background (ie: it tells you there are compile errors), but triggering a real build (or more often clean and then build) will get it through. That's likely what Kevin was experiencing.