# 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserManager' and no extension method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

The following code is copied from the Asp.Net Identity 2.0 sample.

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return // Error 
          _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

However it gets the following error?

> Error 3   'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserManager' and no extension method 'GetUserManager' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Update:**

The version 2 of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll already exists in ...\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.0.1\lib\net45.

However, the view definition of `HttpContext.GetOwinContext()` are different between my project and the sample. The first three lines of my project are

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll, v2.0.0.0
// C:\......\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.2.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll
#endregion
```

while the sample is

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll, v2.1.0.0
// C:\....\sample\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll
#endregion
```

But I already updated all Owin Nuget packages to the newest version using Neget.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net WebAPI can't find Request.GetOwinContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598567/asp-net-webapi-cant-find-request-getowincontext)

Comment: `GetOwinContext()` works fine in my code though. `GetUserManager()` has problem.

Comment: Did you follow the steps specified here under "Download this release"? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx

Comment: @KevinJunghans Yes, I following it for upgrading my project. I remember there was some errors at beginning and I did retry.

Comment: Are you in a Controller or an ApiController?

Answer (score 83):

The extension method was moved to a different namespace, try adding

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```