# Accessing UserManager outside AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, actioncontroller

I am trying to set the value of a column in `aspnetuser` table from a different controller (not `accountcontroller`). I have been trying to access `UserManager` but I can't figure our how to do it.

So far I have tried the following in the controller I want to use it in:

```
    ApplicationUser u = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    u.IsRegComplete = true;
    UserManager.Update(u);
```

This would not compile (I think because `UserManager` has not been instantiated the controller)

I also tried to create a public method in the `AccountController` to accept the value I want to change the value to and do it there but I can't figure out how to call it.

```
public void setIsRegComplete(Boolean setValue)
{
    ApplicationUser u = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    u.IsRegComplete = setValue;
    UserManager.Update(u);

    return;
}
```

How do you access and edit user data outside of the Account Controller?

UPDATE:

I tried to instantiate the UserManager in the other controller like so:

```
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
    ApplicationUser u = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

I the project complied (got a little excited) but when I ran the code I get the following error:

```
Additional information: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.
```

UPDATE 2:

I have moved the function to the IdentityModel (don't ask I am clutching at straws here) like so:

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public Boolean IsRegComplete { get; set; }

        public void SetIsRegComplete(string userId, Boolean valueToSet)
        {

            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());
            ApplicationUser u = new ApplicationUser();
            u = userManager.FindById(userId);

            u.IsRegComplete = valueToSet;
            return;
        }
    }
```

However I am still getting the following:

```
The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.
```

There is also the following class in IdentitiesModels.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? It feels like I am completely barking up the wrong tree. All I am trying to do is update a column in aspnetuser table from the action of a different controller (i.e not the AccountsController).

Comment: It seems from the error message like the "db" you're passing to the store, is not the same DbContext that contains your Identity tables.

Comment: do you have `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>{}` in your `db` context class?

Comment: `var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ApplicationDbContext.Create()));`

Comment: Yup, That worked a treat. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet to comment, so I am making a new an answer post. Just to add to @Iravanchi answer the extension method for GetOwinContext() has been moved to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532964/microsoft-owin-iowincontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getusermanager

Answer (score 35):

If you're using the default project template, the `UserManager` gets created the following way:

In the Startup.Auth.cs file, there's a line like this:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

that makes OWIN pipeline instantiate an instance of `ApplicationUserManager` each time a request arrives at the server. You can get that instance from OWIN pipeline using the following code inside a controller:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
```

If you look carefully at your `AccountController` class, you'll see the following pieces of code that makes access to the `ApplicationUserManager` possible:

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Please note, that in case you need to instantiate the `ApplicationUserManager` class, you need to use the `ApplicationUserManager.Create` static method so that you have the appropriate settings and configuration applied to it.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. The suggestion in the comment above worked. I kept the code in the IdentityModels.cs file as I will need to access it in multiple places.

Comment: I suggest that you retrieve the `UserManager` from OWIN context instead of creating a new instance, as it is created in each request anyway, and creating a new one is redundant overhead.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to get UserManager's instance in another **Controller** just add its parameter in Controller's constructor like this

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public MyController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;;
    }
}
```

But I have to get UserManager in a class that is not controller !

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I am considering you are using asp.net core

Comment: But how to you pass it to your controller in the first place? I have no references to my controller in my entire project, so I don't know how to pass it a reference to the userManager? Where is it actually instantiated?

Comment: No no. UserManager<ApplicationUser> will be injected to your application controllers from your startup.cs class. 
Make an ASP.NET Identity project in ASP.NET Core and see the startup.cs class.
The following code is injecting UserManager<Application> Instance to your controllers

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: So I see, lots of magic going on. Hard to follow when all the code that does this stuff is hidden away.

Comment: If I try this, I get an error that the controller has no default constructor.

Comment: @JonathanWood try to make another constructor with empty parameters then chek

Comment: @ДвυΒдкдя: Yes, of course. But then I don't have a `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` instance.

Comment: @JonathanWood create a new asp.net core application with user authentication and see AccountController

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and modified my code to pass a reference to the UserManager class from the Controller to the Model:

```
//snippet from Controller
public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateUser(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{
    return Json(await UserIdentityDataAccess.UpdateUser(UserManager, applicationUser));
}

//snippet from Data Model
public static async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateUser(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{
    applicationUser.UserName = applicationUser.Email;
    var result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(applicationUser);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOR MVC 5**

> The steps to access usermanger or createUser outside Account controller is easy. Follow the below steps

1. Create a controller, consider SuperAdminController
2. Decorate the SuperAdminController same as the AccountController as below,

   ```
   private readonly IAdminOrganizationService _organizationService;
   private readonly ICommonService _commonService;
   private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
   private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

   public SuperAdminController()
   {
   }

   public SuperAdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
   {
       UserManager = userManager;
       SignInManager = signInManager;
   }

   public SuperAdminController(IAdminOrganizationService organizationService, ICommonService commonService)
   {
       if (organizationService == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("organizationService");


       if (commonService == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("commonService");

       _organizationService = organizationService;
       _commonService = commonService;
   }


   public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
   {
       get
       {
           return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
       }
       private set
       {
           _signInManager = value;
       }
   }


   public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
   {
       get
       {
           return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
       }
       private set
       {
           _userManager = value;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create User in Action method

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<ActionResult> AddNewOrganizationAdminUser(UserViewModel userViewModel)
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return View(userViewModel);
       }

       var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = userViewModel.Email, Email = userViewModel.Email };
       var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userViewModel.Password);
       if (result.Succeeded)
       {
           var model = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, tblUser>(userViewModel);

           var success = _organizationService.AddNewOrganizationAdminUser(model);

           return RedirectToAction("OrganizationAdminUsers", "SuperAdmin");

       }
       AddErrors(result);
       return View(userViewModel);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the UserManager outside of a controller you can use the following:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
var applicationManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);
```