# How to run self-hosted(owin based) web api on IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-host-webapi

I have developed self-hosted(owin based) web api using console application.

In development phase I was running the console application and everything was okay.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string baseUri = "http://+:8080";

        Console.WriteLine("Starting web Server...");
        var server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUri);
        Console.WriteLine("Server running at {0} - press Enter to quit. ", baseUri);
        Console.ReadLine();
        server.Dispose();
    }
```

Now I need to deploy my self-hosted web api to run on IIS.So, could you please tell me the steps to get my web api up and running on IIS?

Answer (score 3):

In order to understand theory - [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610064/relationship-between-webapi-webhost-and-owin). If you want your OWIN self-hosted WEB API application to be running on IIS, you need to use [Owin.Host.SystemWeb package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/). You should:

- Add a Startup.cs class (entry point for your IIS-hosted app)
- Tell OWIN pipeline about your entrypoint: Mark Startup class with
  owin    attribute OR do it via web.config. ([See this article for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection))

P.S. You can always take a look at a standard scaffolded empty Web API project in Visual Studio. It includes IIS web host out-of-the-box

Comment: I just can't seem to get this to work. IIS just tried to display files. Do you need to change the project type (it's a console app still) or anything like that? I'd love it if I could run both ways...

Comment: Yes, without proper web.config file and global.asax in your application package IIS won't consider site as .net web application. If you want your application to be self hosted + IIS hosted simultaneously, you can create additional projects in your solution: one of type console application and another web application (VS will scaffold config, asax and all IIS-startup stuff for you).  This projects will refer the same assemblies of you application, but differ from startup perspective: one for IIS, another for self-hosted console app