# GetOwinContext in ASP.NET5 / MVC6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In WebApi I used to do this on my BaseApiController:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", new[] { Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader) });
```

I'm converting to ASP.NET v5, and I get the error:

```
HttpRequest does not contain a definition for GetOwinContext
```

Any pointers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598567/asp-net-webapi-cant-find-request-getowincontext

check this link

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. I don't think it's relevant to ASP.NET v5 / MVC6?

Comment: Try this.

OwinContext owinContext = (OwinContext)Request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that, surely? Every time I want to do something like `GetUserManager` I have to cast the context?

Comment: we use owin hosting for my webapi , i did't find a easy way of retrieving the owin context from the request. we this "OwinContext owinContext = (OwinContext)Request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];".

Comment: Ok, but the MVC6 Request object doesn't have a Properties property...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 is not based on OWIN, so don't expect `GetOwinContext()` to work.

Your code can be easily adapted to the new `HttpResponse` primitive:

```
Response.Headers["X-Pagination"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader);
```

Comment: Can I not use OWIN with ASP.NET 5? I wanted a lightweight api, but with V5, is that not possible?

Comment: MVC 6 doesn't use OWIN. It directly relies on the new `HttpContext`/`HttpRequest`/`HttpResponse` primitives exposed by ASP.NET 5.

Comment: Ok, then I'm really lost. Is that the end of the road for OWIN? I thought it was the new, lean, composable way of building web systems. I struggled to get my system to use it and now it seems I backed the wrong horse?

Comment: No, OWIN is still supported via an adapter, but ASP.NET 5 is not-OWIN-based. Anyway, you have no reason to use OWIN when working with MVC 6.