# 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext' in c# .net framwork 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, openid-connect

Hi I'm trying to add OpenID connect and this run this code in application

```
 protected void btnLoginopenID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied2.aspx", false);
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

and I'm getting this error message when trying to run code

> CS1061    'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext' and no extension method 'GetOwinContext' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ0m5.png)

i did try

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

but didn't work for me any suggestion to fix t his issue or also if you know any way to integrate OpenID Connect to C# .net framework 4.5 for WebForm.aspx please let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find Request.GetOwinContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598567/cant-find-request-getowincontext)

Comment: Others fixed this by installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin and by using the namespace `System.Net.Http`

Comment: i used but didn't not fixed the issue. I'm trying this now since morning

Comment: you need the correct `using` too since this is an extension method

Answer (score 0):

it's missing package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).