# 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

I get the error :

> 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetOwinContext' and no extension method 'GetOwinContext' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It seems you have missing NuGet package called 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'. Install package from NuGet or use package manager console to install the package.

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Hope this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148209/asp-net-identity-httpcontext-has-no-extension-method-for-getowincontext

Comment: Confirm this helped! Thanks