# 'System.Web.HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext' Mystery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I realize this question might seem trivial to some, but it's these types of things that I find myself fighting with quite a bit and I just want to make sense of it all despite that seeming to be a losing battle in .net (for me anyway).

So, if I do the following:

```
    using System.Web;
...
ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

That produces the error in the title and a red `GetOwinContext()` and the error ***Cannot resolve symbol 'GetOwinContext()'***

However, if I do the following (remove `System.Web` from in front of `HttpContext`), it works as expected (or at least no errors):

```
using System.Web;
    ...
    ApplicationUser user = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

However, if I do this (same line that's working with `using System.Web` commented out):

```
    //using System.Web;
            ...
ApplicationUser user = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

It produces the same red `GetOwinContext()` and the error ***Cannot resolve symbol 'GetOwinContext()'***

If I google `HttpContext` I can only find that it stems from `System.Web`.

So, the question is why can't I use the full syntax like in the first example above? (Also mentioned in the answer here with the highest votes: [ASP.NET MVC 5 - Identity. How to get current ApplicationUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-mvc5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser))

**UPDATE** (to address duplicate question reply): While there is an answer on that question that may come to the same conclusion, I don't really understand how this is a duplicate question. Try to think of it from a newbie perspective and dissecting all the smoke and mirrors that is .Net. I have never tried to learn something so convoluted in my life as .Net and sometimes you have to look at things from many different angles.

I actually saw that question and one other regarding using `Current,` but neither struck me as 1) being the answer I was looking for (at the time) 2) more importantly, why it's behaving like that. Sam's answer is perfect, although a bit over my head. But, at least now, I can go research what it all means...

Comment: from what i've seen controllers have their own HttpContext  `Controller.HttpContext` and there is a `System.Web.HttpContext`  Controller.HttpContext has GetOwinContext().. both have session too but think for one second they're the same either :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Identity - HttpContext has no extension method for GetOwinContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148209/asp-net-identity-httpcontext-has-no-extension-method-for-getowincontext)

Comment: I blame [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members) for this one, I personally never liked having property named same as the type. Also the 3rd issue stems from the extension missing if it isn't clear (see @NightOwl888 's link above)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you are writing `System.Web.HttpContext` actually you are pointing to a class. But when you are writing `HttpContext` inside of a controller you are using a property named `HttpContext` which returns an object of the `HttpContext` class. You could also reach the same object by calling the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` static property. Therefore you could write:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Comment: I saw the `Current` over here in this SO question ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431820/system-web-httpcontextbase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-current-mvc-4-wi)). Unfortunately, I lost my undos after my computer crashed last night, but I think I tried to put it after `GetOwinContext()` like a dope. I think your answer is a little over my head at the moment, but I can at least research now and digest... Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

Just go to NuGet Packages Manager of the project, search and install this `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` and you can use `using System.Web;` to enable `GetOwinContext()` method

Answer (score 11):

DSR's answer in this link worked for me

[Working in MVC 5 Identity for email verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200043/working-in-mvc-5-identity-for-email-verification)

It seems you have a missing NuGet package called 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'. Install this package from NuGet or use the package manager console to install said package.

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked in my case; I had been cherry picking the Owin packages and had accidentally left this one out! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks 
it works in my case when i added `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` from `NugetpackageManager.`
It provides the extension method `GetOwinContext()` to the `HttpContext`.