# OWIN Challenge method does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm trying to integrate a Microsoft account login into my ASP.NET MVC app, and I have this controller method:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    // HACK - we will be signed into only one account if we are not signed in to MS
    if (Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identities.Count() <= 1)
    {
        // Signal OWIN to send an authorization request to Azure
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "http://localhost:31503/MicrosoftCalendar" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen is that I'm prompted to log in to my Microsoft account; instead, what happens is this method runs over and over and over again, doing nothing at all, until I get a "too many redirects" error in my browser. How can I get the `Challenge` method to actually do something?

I have a class `OwinStartup` in my web project; I have it set to be the OWIN startup class like so:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Root.OwinStartup))]
```

However for some reason my breakpoints inside this startup class never get hit; OWIN is never being initialized... actually, wait a second, it is being initialized, but the event handlers for things like `OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync` are never being hit...

If I step through the code, after `Challenge` is called in the `SignIn` method, I get redirected for some reason to a `UserController`, which in turn redirects me back to the `SignIn` method. I wonder why I'm winding up in the `UserController`?

edit: I need more code? all right, this method in Global.asax.cs executes immediately after the OWIN calls:

```
protected void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region Set the context GUID cookie
    if (null == Request.Cookies[CookieName.ContextGUID])
    {
        Response.SetCookie(new System.Web.HttpCookie(CookieName.ContextGUID, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
    }
    #endregion

    // check to see whether SSL is required
    if (System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL)
    {
        // check where the request is originating from
        if (Request.UserHostName != "127.0.0.1" && Request.UserHostName != "localhost")
        {
            // check if the request is secure
            if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                string url = null;
                // check for querystring segments
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]))
                {
                    url = String.Format("https://{0}{1}?{2}",
                        Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"],
                        Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"],
                        Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    url = String.Format("https://{0}{1}", Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"], Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
                }

                // redirect to the secure url
                Response.Redirect(url);
            }
        }
    }

    // verify the request
    if (null != Request)
    {
        // NOTE: This is a workaround for the following exception thrown by the ReportViewer control when
        //  using a non-IE browser:
        //      Missing URL parameter: IterationId
        // See the following reference: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556989/?wa=wsignin1.0
        if (Request.Path.EndsWith("Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd") &&
            Request.QueryString["ResourceStreamID"] != null &&
            Request.QueryString["ResourceStreamID"].ToLower().Contains("blank.gif"))
        {
            // intercept the request and send to actual valid image path
            Response.Redirect(Constant.ImageRoot + "blank.gif");
        }
    }

}
```

Not sure if this is what's causing the infinite redirect loop but here it is...

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using ?  are you using .net core or .Net framework ?  What is name of startup class ? If it is owinstartup, did you try changing it to just "Startup" ?

Comment: Using ASP.NET MVC, I think either version 2 or version 5; I remember having to upgrade at one point but I'm not 100% sure. This is .NET Framework. Startup class is called OwinStartup; I tried renaming it to Startup but that didn't help.

Comment: You will have to post sufficient code to understand and replicate the issue.  WIthout the code, it is very difficult to guess the solution.

Comment: OK, what code would you like to see? The OwinStartup class, maybe?

Comment: @ekolis You definitely need to provide more code for context. Very difficult to troubleshoot with just what you provided.

Comment: All right, I've posted some more code - not sure if it's relevant but I shared the method that runs immediately after the OWIN calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a shot in the dark, but it looks like the controller isn't returning anything because it is a void method, try adding a return type, I'm not overly familier with OWIN so you'll have to forgive me there but here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{

   // Signal OWIN to send an authorization request to Azure
   return Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "http://localhost:31503/MicrosoftCalendar" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

}
```

two small changes which are in the method signature, returning `ActionResult` and not a void, you may have to do a bit of research here on the class that OWIN actually returns. and second adding the `return` keyword, note this will not work with the if statement that you have said is a "hack" because you would require two return statements in that scenario

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I don't think that will work; the `Challenge` method is also void. It's a mystery to me how that method works...

Comment: Similar question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056143/httpcontext-current-getowincontext-authentication-challenge-does-not-open-ad

Comment: thanks, tried that but I still get caught in an endless redirect loop...