# HttpContextBase namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
{
    if (context.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            context.Session[CartSessionKey] =
                context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class
            Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
            // Send tempCartId back to client as a cookie
            context.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
        }
    }

    return context.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
}
```

Any help on the work around with HttpContextBase in asp.net core? above is my sample code am working on to create a shopping cart.

Comment: You can use HttpContextBase abstractContext = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(context);

Comment: @Tomato32 There is no `System.Web` in ASP.NET Core anymore

Comment: Are you doing this outside of a controller ?

Comment: Try this answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431820/system-web-httpcontextbase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-current-mvc-4-wi)

Comment: I don't know if it's important or not, but guid's aren't guaranteed to be random, they are only guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is no `HttpContextBase` in ASP.NET Core. `HttpContext` is already an abstract class (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs#L16)) which is implemented in `DefaultHttpContext` (see [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/DefaultHttpContext.cs#L16)). Just use `HttpContext`.

Comment: `public string GetCartId(HttpContext context)
       ` This worked.

Comment: Mark it as accepted, if it solves your problem so it doesn't appear in the "unanswered" section anymore

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: @Jeppe: Links updated and pinned to the 2.2 release

Answer (score 3):

I had to modify like below

```
public string GetCartId(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Session.GetString(CartSessionKey) == null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            context.Session.SetString(CartSessionKey, context.User.Identity.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            var tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
            context.Session.SetString(CartSessionKey, tempCartId.ToString());
        }
    }

    return context.Session.GetString(CartSessionKey);
}
```

It may help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

using `net5` and `autofac` I found the following solved my needs. something feels a bit hackish about this and I will update if this solution evolves.

- add binding for `HttpContextAccessor` to autofac

  ```
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
        // ...
        builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>()
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();
  ```
- add dependency to `HttpContextAccessor` in

  ```
  private readonly HttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  ```
- access current context `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext`