# Pass a value from route to custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a custom attribute and I need to pass a value from route to this attribute, how can I do this?

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(string myvalue)
    {
        // use myvalue...
    }
}

[MyAttribute]
[Route("/action/{myvalue}")]
public IActionResult Action(string myvalue)
{
   
}
```

Comment: If you really mean this is an `asp.net core` question, you need `IHttpContextAccessor` instead of `HttpContextBase` which is really gone away in the world `asp.net core`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can inject `HttpContextAccessor` to your attribute class and then read the route parameters

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly HttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public MyAttribute(HttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor; 
        var myValue = _accessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues.GetValueOrDefault["myValue"];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you knew really well about the OP's question when he tagged his question as `asp.net-core` but looks like it's actually for the old `asp.net`, because there is no `HttpContextBase` in `asp.net-core` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775390/httpcontextbase-namespace-could-not-be-found  So the answer and the question both confuse the readers, really bad. At least you should've mentioned about that in your answer.

Comment: also with the usage of this attribute by the OP `[MyAttribute]`, how could this be used at all? We have way to use it but really this answer does not talk about that and the OP (at his level of understanding) seems to automatically know how to use that attribute, what a genius.

Comment: no actually logically, this is so strange. It's really like you and the OP are one person, ***really*** or at least there is some close relationship in real life.

Comment: you're welcome. btw it's worth it because as I said it's confusing. Unless someone edits the question's tag to replace `asp.net-core` with `asp.net`.

Comment: how can I use this attribute in my controller?

Comment: checkout this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis

Comment: @AliFaris in the controller i need to pass instead of HttpContextAccessor  , how can i inject this to attribute?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand you

Comment: @AliFaris I hope you will by checking this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981258/dependency-injection-in-custom-attribute