# ASP.NET Web API - Cannot upload base64 image

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Environment: ASP.NET Web API
.NET Core 2.1

I just started working on ASP.NET Web API and stuck in uploading base64 image.
Here is my code:

```
public bool UploadFile(string base64String)
    {
        try
        {
            var folderName = Constant.PATH_ITEM_IMAGES;

            string defaultImagePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/images");

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                Image pic = Image.FromStream(ms);

                pic.Save(defaultImagePath);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Both HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~") or Server.MapPath does not work.
Also, Image cannot be found

I'm using Nuget Package manager to manage dependencies. What am I missing here?
Any package I need to add?

This did not help either:

[System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' MVC 4 with Elmah Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431820/system-web-httpcontextbase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-current-mvc-4-wi)

Comment: What does "Image cannot be found" mean? is your base64 string empty?

Answer (score 0):

Use **HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath**

```
public bool UploadFile(string base64String)
    {
        try
        {
            var folderName = Constant.PATH_ITEM_IMAGES;
            string defaultImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/");

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                Image pic = Image.FromStream(ms);
                string imageName  = "";//get image name (pic.png)
                string picPath = defaultImagePath  + imageName;
                pic.Save(defaultImagePath);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and when try save image give it name and combine it with target folder.