# Export multiple datagrids to different worksheets on a single excel file

Tags: asp.net, sql, export-to-excel

My code here runs a stored procedure that retrieves multiple reports for each customer. All these reports are viewed within the same sheet in excel. Can someone tell me how I can make my report viewed on multiple excel-sheets instead of 1 only??

```
 using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("databases.dbo.SP_GetAll_Reports",    connection))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = custName;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
            {
                Session["TaskTable"] = dt;
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    foreach(DataTable table in dt.Tables)
                    {
                         HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                        dg.DataSource = table;
                        dg.DataBind();
                        dg.RenderControl(hw);
                    }
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachchment;       filename=Report_Accounting.xls");
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.End();
                }
```

Comment: You can do it manually using `EPPlus`.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean manually? The data retrieved for each customer is very dynamic, it could be 3 reports or it could be 20. That's why I need the sheets to be created after how many reports/data my datagrid is retrieving for each customer.

Comment: I mean loop through the datatable and write the excel file using `EPPlus`.

Comment: Actually it's very easy with `EPPlus`. check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus

Comment: Thanks for your link! But I still can't see how to put this code with my code above and also I'm missing the ExcelPackage in my visual studio.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install `EPPlus` using **Nuget Package manager**

1. right click you project
2. select **Nuget Package Manager**
3. Search for `EPPlus`
4. Click install

then change your code to this

```
using OfficeOpenXml;


 using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("databases.dbo.SP_GetAll_Reports",    connection))
 {
     sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = custName;
     using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
     {
         Session["TaskTable"] = dt;
         sqlDa.Fill(dt);
         if (dt.Tables.Count > 0)
         {
             MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
             int i=1;
             using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
             {
                 foreach(DataTable table in dt.Tables)
                 {
                     ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet"+i++);
                     worksheet.Cell["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true); 
                 }
                 Response.Clear(); 
                 package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
                 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachchment;       filename=Report_Accounting.xls");
                 Response.Charset = "";
                 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                 Response.End();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: file extension should be `xlsx`, not `xls`. It won't open on Excel 2003 or lower. Though you can install compatibility plugin to Excel 2003 which will enable it to open the file.