# Generate Excel File using C# without Office tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

Currently I am using **[EPPlus Library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)** mainly because **EPPPlus** doesn't need of office installed on End user pc but right now i've been specifying(insert) each row and column in to worksheet on this library.

I want to generate the excel file from **GRIDVIEW** data on server side without office tool.

So i need some other solution or Library file that could meet my expectation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact problem you encountered with `EPPLus`?

Comment: Gridiview isn't a data structure, it's a UI. Which means your data is either a DataTable or a list of objects. Writing a few lines of code to iterate over this and set cell values is almost trivial

Comment: I need to specify each cell value with rows and columns to insert in excel file @Tim Schmelter

Comment: Why is that a problem and what do you want to do something else? Creating a generic method to do the job isn't difficult and doesn't need any external tool. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @JoeMike: you can do that with `EPPLus`, but i don't understand why you want to use the complicated way if you can use the `LoadFromDataTable` or `LoadFromCollection`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export DataTable to excel with EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must admit that i don't understand why you can't use `EPPlus` with the `GridView`.

You could use the `DataSource` of the `GridView`, for example if it's a `DataTable`:

```
try {
    var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet-Name");
    ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, false);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=FileName.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //log error
}
Response.End();
```