# Not getting anything out of my xmlNodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I've write a quick code to try getting elements from an XML file and put them in an excel table but I don't get anyhting out of my nodes. I don't understand why.

I've been trying different mean of getting what I need from my nodes using the microsoft documentation of XMLDocument but the result is always the same, it's printing me empty lines.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
        int rowCount = 1;

        openFileDialog.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
        openFileDialog.Title = "Select the SMS backup";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            try
            {
                xmlDocument.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
            }
            table.Columns.Add("Contact name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DataFormats));
            table.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
                if (node.InnerText.Contains("contact_name"))
                {
                    table.Rows.Add(
                        node.Attributes["contact_name"]?.InnerText,
                        node.Attributes["readable_date"]?.InnerText,
                        node.Attributes["body"]?.InnerText
                        );
                }
            }
            try
            {
                excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
                {
                    Visible = true,
                    DisplayAlerts = false
                };
                workBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) workBook.ActiveSheet;
                workSheet.Name = "SMS backup";
                foreach (System.Data.DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
                {
                    rowCount += 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dataRow[i - 1].ToString();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                workSheet = null;
                workBook = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use EPplus, read your xml file into a datatable, output to excel. It'll take about 10 lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, here's a bit more in depth advice. I'm writing this on a cell phone so please forgive that it's not a full working code

Right click your solution node in solution explorer and choose Manage Nuget packages for solution

Install epplus - it creates excel files directly (they're actually just xml files inside a zip file named xlsx) without needing excel installed  interop can be a pain in the backside and is best avoided

Read your xml document into a dataset:

```
DataSet da = new DataSet();
da.ReadXml(path to your file);
```

Place a breakpoint on the readxml line and launch the app. Step over the readxml then point to `ds`and click the magnifying glass that appears in the tooltip

Familiarise yourself with how the xml document is presented in the DataSet - nodes that have child nodes tend to be represented as separated tables with relations linking them together, so you might end up, for an xml like

```
xml
  parentnode1
    childnode1
  parentnode2
    childnode2
/xml
```

You'd have two tables, called parentnode and childnode, and you'd read them in a loopset like:

```
foreach(var ro in da.Tables["parentnode"].Rows)
  //do stuff with parent rows

  //iterate child rows
  foreach(var cro in ro.GetChildRows()){
    //do stuff with child rows
  }
}
```

It doesn't look like your xml is structured this way right now but it's not easy to tell

So, you now have your xml document as a set of tables in a DataSet and you want them as an excel sheet. Epplus can create an excel file from a datatable (a DataSet is a collection of datatables) in a few lines of code, see [Export DataTable to excel with EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus)

If your DataSet only contains 1 table then the job is pretty much over. If it has multiple tables I recommend you make yourself a new DataTable then loop over the DataSet picking values out of various ds.Tables["table name here"] and populating your DataTable

Thus to implement your program implement this set of comments as code

```
//read xml file to DataSet - 2 lines of code

//EITHER xml is flat structure, results in one datatable in the set 
//so just remove or rename columns as required - few lines

//OR DataSet has 3 tables, make a new datatable and loop over the 3, 
//populating the new one, to flatten it - few lines

//use epplus to turn the single datatable to an excel sheet - 4 lines
```

Problem solved, hopefully in around 10 lines of code