# How to export datagridview checkbox column values saved in a list, into excel

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a `class` and a `Form1`. In my `class` I have created variables to save my data.

**Savestate.cs**

```
public static List<string> plate_list = new List<string>();
public static List<string> checkbox_list = new List<string>();
```

Then in my `Form1`, I saved the data of `textbox1` and  `chk` into the variables through `button1`. Both datas are respective of each other. Then I export them into excel through `button2`. Below is my code:

**Form1.cs**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Savestate.plate_list.Add(textbox1.Text);
 foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
 {
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = dataGridRow.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
   if (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(chk.Value)) == true)
     {
      Savestate. checkbox_list.Add("P");
     }
   else if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == false)
     {
      Savestate. checkbox_list.Add("O");
     }
  }
}

//snippet of codes for exporting variables into excel
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  int _lastRow1 = oSheet1.Range["C" + oSheet1.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;
  rng = oSheet1.Range[oSheet1.Cells[_lastRow1, 2], oSheet1.Cells[_lastRow1, 10]];

   foreach (var data in Savestate.plate_list)
        {
          oSheet1.Cells[_lastRow1, 1] = data;
          foreach (var other in Savestate. checkbox_list)
          {
           rng.Value = other;
           (another loop here to read the checkbox list values?)
           }
            _lastRow1++;
        }
 }
```

With these codes, I am able to loop through my plate number correctly but for my checkbox values, only the latest values are exported, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIQOx.png) (I saved 2 plate numbers so there should be 2 sets of checkbox values but only 1 set of checkbox values are exported).  I feel that I have to make another loop specifically for the checkbox values but I don’t know how to start. Hope to get some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is would be a lot easier if you do the following:

- Right click the project in solution explorer
- Choose Add New...
- Add a new DataSet to the project
- Double click the DataSet, something like a database designer appears
- Right click the design surface, choose New DataTable, name it suitably
- Right click the DataTable repeatedly, choosing Add Column and add all the columns you want to keep your data in. Set the type of each column e.g. String, Int, Boolean etc
- Save your DataSet
- Switch back to your forms designer, go into the relevant menu to show the "Data Sources" window for your version of visual studio. Google if you don't know how to show this. Example, for vs 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-data-sources?view=vs-2017#data-sources-window
- In the data sources window is a tree and one of the nodes is your DataTable. Drag it onto the forms designer. A datagridview appears with columns suitably types for the data. Bool columns are a checkbox. The datagridview is wired up to a DataSet object that contains an instance of your datatable. Anything you type into the grid is stored in the datatable. You can delete the bindingnavigator that appears if you don't want it
- Right click on the solution in solution explorer, choose Manage Nuget Packages For Solution
- In the nugget package manager, click Browse and Then type EPPLUS in the search box. Install the epplus library into your project. Close the nuget package manager
- Double click your save button on your form. Add the ~3 lines of code necessary to have epplus create your excel file from your DataTable. More information can be found here: [Export DataTable to excel with EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus)

---

in that link, you need to substitute the name of your DataTable into the LoadFromDataTable call. It is inside the DataSet on your from, so will be something like `yourDataSetName.YourDataTabkeName`

---

The above is the embodiment of a concept called MVC- model, view, controller. The essence of this is that your data lives in a dedicated container called the Model (the DataSet/DataTable in this example), and it is shown on screen by the View (datagridview) and Controlled/changed by something else again (though in this example and in many, the datagridview is also the controller, to some extent). The days of dropping a complex control on a form, like a gridview, and storing the data inside it were supposed to have been over with VB6 :). Though it is still sometimes more convenient to store data on e.g. Textboxes and dig it out with textbox.Text for simple scenarios, these controls all support data binding and the idea that if your program is haoldibg multiple data records and paging through them, means that all the data should be stored in a model, all the controls that show it and edit it connect to the model and they all understand the concept of navigating through the model- you change the current record your referring to in the model and all the text boxes etc change the data they are showing, automatically. You don't go into each control and push data in there repeatedly, and dig it out later yourself

Once you understand the MVC paradigm it opens you up to using functionality where other developers have targeted it too in this case EPPlus, you can just hand it the data model (DataSet/DataTable) and say "here, write this to a file" and it'll do it. You cannot hand your datagridview to epplus, because data is not supposed to be stored in a datagridview according to MVC principles so epplus doesn't support digging data out of it

If nothing else, hopefully you can appreciate that the above set of steps, though looking long when Ive typed it out, actually involve less time, fewer mouse clicks, and considerably fewer lines of code than you've already written so far.

Comment: Hai Caius. Theanks for the pointers. I'm new to datasets and Ive followed step by step. My dataset name is **Checkbox** and my datatable name is **checkboxDataGridView**. So based on your link for the ~3 line codes, my 2nd line is `ws.Cells["A1"].Checkbox.checkboxDataGridView(checkboxDataGridView, true);`. But when I do this, I get error `ExcelRange does not contain a definition for Checkbox`. What did I do wrong? Will appreciate the help.