# How to save Datasource in a List<string> (no sqlconnection etc)

Tags: c#, list, winforms, dataset

I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567266/how-to-export-datagridview-checkbox-column-values-saved-in-a-list-into-excel) but in my case I need to store multiple sets of datasets for an unknown number of times, not just once. So that is why I am asking here again.

I have multiple `datatables` with 2 columns in each `datatable`. One of them is a `bool` column (checkbox values). The checkbox values are empty when the form loads so up to user to check or uncheck them. Upon updating the checkbox, user press `button1` to save only checkbox values in a `dataset` and this `dataset` will be saved in a List.

These datatables will then empty out and the same steps repeat for an unknown number of times (form loads empty datatables, user update checkboxes, user press button1). I have used the method below. No errors but when I want to display the List value in `datagridview1` in `Form2`, it was empty. Below is my code. Hope to get help, thanks!

**Class 1.cs (where I initiated my List)**

```
public static List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

**Form1.cs**

```
//Create dataset
private DataSet Getdataset()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(bool));
        dt1.Rows.Add("hello");
        dt1.Rows.Add("hello");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
        dgv1.DataSource = dt1;
        dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(string));
        dt2.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(bool));
        dt2.Rows.Add("bye");
        dt2.Rows.Add("bye");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
        dgv2.DataSource = dt2;
        dgv2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        return ds;
    }

//Save dataset in a List
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dd = Getdataset();
        foreach (DataTable table in dd.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Class1.list.Add(Convert.ToString(row["Status"]));
            }
        }

        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**Form2.cs**

```
//Display dataset in datagridview
private void compile_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
        foreach (string item in Class1.list)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = item;
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

**EDIT**
As per er-sho comment, I added a messagebox in the code per below and it showed `Systems.Collection.Generic.List1[System.String]` 7 times (I have 6 checkboxes). There was still no display in the `datagridview1` and I initialized the no. of columns, headers for `datagridview1` to avoid compilation error. However, see below comment under Gokham’s solution (seems like the data in List is not per expected)

```
foreach (string item in Class1.list)
{
 MessageBox.Show(Class1.list.ToString());
 row.Cells[0].Value = item;
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that in `Form2` is there `Class1.List` is empty or not? after clicking button in `Form1`

Comment: It should be exception in line with
`DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();` because dataGridView1 has not rows yet

Comment: @er-sho I use messagebox to see if there are any data in the list. But as per edited code, the List is not what I expected. :(

Comment: @IvanTikhonov. Now I understand what the clone line is for. And yes, after I put messagebox then it show exception. So I realised my current method of using `clone` to show the List contents is incorrect. Hence, I’ve followed Gokhan solution to display my List contents.  But the List is not what I expected :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime, when you click `button1`, you rewrite your data in `dgv1` with default values:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Rows.Add("hello");
dt1.Rows.Add("hello");
dgv1.DataSource = dt1;
```

`dt1` will be contains rows with only **Item** values, but not with **Status**. You should add code with getting user inputs

**UPDATE**
To achieve the goal you should make follow steps:

1. Init dgv1 - add columns and fill rows with default values

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       UpdateDgv1();
   }

   private void UpdateDgv1()
   {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
       dt1.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(string));
       dt1.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(bool));
       dt1.Rows.Add("hello");
       dt1.Rows.Add("hello");
       ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
       dgv1.DataSource = dt1;
       dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
   }
   ```
2. Get values from dgv1 on button click

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       for (var i = 0; i < dgv1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           list.Add(Convert.ToString(dgv1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value));
       }

       //restore dgv1
       UpdateDgv1();

       Form2 f = new Form2();
       f.ShowDialog();

       //clear list with old values or comment it
       //if you want to save history of user inputs
       list.Clear();
   }
   ```
3. Show list content on datagridview1 of Form2

   ```
   private void Form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
       foreach (string item in Form1.list)
       {
           var newRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

           //if checkbox from Form1 not checked
           if (item == string.Empty)
               dataGridView1.Rows[newRow].Cells[0].Value = false.ToString();
           else
               dataGridView1.Rows[newRow].Cells[0].Value = item;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: HI. Thank you again for your suggestion. I am new so I'm sorry, I’m not sure what you mean. Does it mean repeating `Getdataset();` for button1 click event? I say this because your suggested solution shows a repeat of my dt1.

Answer (score 0):

Your Getdataset() method doesn't fill Status column of the table. Try

```
private DataSet Getdataset()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(string));
    dt1.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(bool));
    DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
    dr["Items"] = "Hello";
    dr["Status"] = checkBox1.Checked;
    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
    ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
    dgv1.DataSource = dt1;
    dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    ...
    return ds;
}
```

I recommend you using BindingList  instead of List and assigning the list as the DataSource for dataGridView1.

```
public static BindingList<string> list = new BindingList<string>();
```

Form 2

```
private void compile_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Class1.list;
}
```

I think using FormLoad event handler instead of VisibleChanged should be better in your case.

Have a look : [Binding List<T> to DataGridView in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your suggestion. Your solution showed datas. The `datagridview1` displayed one column with values 0 in each row. This is weird as I did check some of the checkboxes, hence the result should be a mix of 1 and 0. Or I would expected a True or a False. And the header is titled “Length” instead of “Status”. Is it because the data inside the List is not my checkbox values?

Comment: Your Getdataset() method doesn't fill Status column of the table. I've updated the answer