# I am getting an error while exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, export-to-excel

I want to transfer the data from dataGridView to Excel. For this, I added the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" plug-in to my project. I wrote the necessary codes properly. But when I run the project and click the "Export to Excel" button, I get an error. What should I do?

**This is my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DuyuTekStokApp
{
    public partial class StockAll : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-L01MAVE;Initial Catalog='StockControl';Integrated Security=True");
        public StockAll()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void VerileriGoster(string Veriler)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Veriler, connect);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridViewAll.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        public void changeHeader()
        {
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Stok Kodu";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Stok Cinsi";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Barkod Numarası";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Birimi";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Grubu";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Tarih";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Açıklama";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Sınıfı";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Değişim Tarihi";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Adeti";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Kritik Miktar";
            dataGridViewAll.Columns[11].HeaderText = "Resim";
        }
        private void StockAll_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connect.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockCard", connect);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                labelToplam.Text = dr1[0].ToString();
            }
            connect.Close();

            connect.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(StokAdet) FROM StockCard", connect);
            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                labelGenel.Text = dr2[0].ToString();
            }
            connect.Close();

            VerileriGoster("SELECT StokKodu, StokCinsi, StokBarkod, StokBirim, StokGrup, StokTarih, StokAciklama, StokSinif, StokSonTarih, StokAdet, StokKritik, StokResim FROM StockCard ORDER BY StokKodu ASC");
            //VerileriGoster(@"SELECT dbo.StockCard.StokKodu, dbo.StockCard.StokBarkod, dbo.StockCard.StokBirim, dbo.StockCard.StokGrup, dbo.StockCard.StokTarih, dbo.StockCard.StokResim, dbo.StockMove.MoveAdet, dbo.StockMove.MoveMevcut, dbo.StockMove.MoveSinif, dbo.StockMove.MoveTarih
            //                     FROM  dbo.StockMove INNER JOIN
            //                  dbo.StockCard ON dbo.StockMove.StokID = dbo.StockCard.StokID ORDER BY StokKodu ASC ");
            changeHeader();
        }

        private void dataGridViewAll_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int secilen = dataGridViewAll.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            labelUrun.Text = dataGridViewAll.Rows[secilen].Cells[9].Value?.ToString();
            labelKrit.Text = dataGridViewAll.Rows[secilen].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])dataGridViewAll.Rows[secilen].Cells[11].Value;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            pictureBoxResim.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }

        private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Stok Bilgisi";

            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridViewAll.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = dataGridViewAll.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewAll.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewAll.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridViewAll.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.FileName = "StokBilgisi";
            saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            app.Quit();

            
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the error message I get:**

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult = 0x80004002
  Message = COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' could not be assigned to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with the IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed with the following error: Error loading type library / DLL. (HRESULT returned exception: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).
  Source = mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW (Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr & ppTarget, Boolean & pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.get_Workbooks ()
   at SenseTekStokApp.StockAll.btnExcel_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e) in D: \ yNs \ VisualTutorials \ SenseTekStokApp \ SenseTekStokApp \ StockAll.cs: line 84
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick (EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick (EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp (MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp (Message & m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (Message & m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc (Message & m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc (Message & m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage (Message & m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (Message & m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback (IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW (MSG & msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop (IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner (Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop (Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (Form mainForm)
   at SenseTekStokApp.Program.Main () in D: \ yNs \ VisualTutorials \ SenseTekStokApp \ SenseTekStokApp \ Program.cs: line 19
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.\_Application'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562540/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationcla)

Comment: There are lots of libraries that will write XLSX files for you. Using Interop is not recommended.

Comment: Nooooo, don't use Interop. You already downloaded your data to a datatable so it's easy to show in your grid with databinding and easy (couple of lines of code) to write to an excel file with something like EPPlus.

Comment: E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus

Comment: Understood. I will try EPPlus. If it happens the way I want, I'll say it here.

Comment: Also really not sure why your stockall load doesn't just `select sum(...) as sumstock, count(*) as countstock from stock` with an adapter into a datatable, or even .. don't bother, just add a couple of columns to your datatable with an .Expression of `"SUM([Price])"` (and another for Count, then the datatable itself will compute the sum and count of its contents (you can also use the Compute method to achieve a similar goal)

Comment: Using epplus  means you /your users don't need Excel installed

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes I made an unreasonable mistake :). I will apply what you say. Thanks for your suggestions. But after I added EPPlus to my project, I did not understand what to do.

Comment: EPPlus works mostly the same as interop in term =s of how you fill values, select ranges, format cells etc, but I gave a link above - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus - this is how to load a *datatable* into epplus and save it as an excel. Your `dataGridViewAll.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` binds a *datatable* to the grid, so really the datatable you want to save as the excel file is `dataGridViewAll.DataSource as DataTable` (and see the linked question for how to save a datatable using EPPlus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps to convert datagirdview to excel.

First, please install nuget-package `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

Second, please using it in the code.

```
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Third, I suggest that you can convert datagirdview to datatable first then you can convert datatable to excel.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            ExportToExcel(table);
        }

 public void ExportToExcel(DataTable tbl )
        {
            try
            {
                if (tbl == null || tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                var workbook=excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                // single worksheet
                Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                // column headings
                for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

                // rows
                for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // to do: format datetime values before printing
                    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tbl.Rows[i][j];
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog.FileName = "StokBilgisi";
                    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
                    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    }
                    excelApp.Quit();
                    Console.WriteLine("Excel file saved!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                    + ex.Message);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This wedding worked somehow. But when I clicked the button, I got an error. "System.Exception
  HResult = 0x80131500
  Message = ExportToExcel:
HRESULT returned exception: 0x800A03EC "gave this error. Could there be a problem with" Excel "installed on my computer?

Comment: @YunusEmreSöğüt, based on my research, you can check if your file is end with xlsx. If not, please change it into test.xlsx.

Comment: @YunusEmreSöğüt, you can accept it as an answer so that others can solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, to use EPPlus (per comments) to save your grid to an excel file:

```
private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
  saveFileDialog.FileName = "StokBilgisi";
  saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
  if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {

    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName)))
    {
      ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("StokBilgisi");
      ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataGridViewAll.DataSource as DataTable, true);
      pck.Save();
    }
  }
```

This is [the code from the linked question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus), adjusted for your context by insertion of `dataGridViewAll.DataSource as DataTable` to retrieve the datatable you bound to the grid when you called `dataGridViewAll.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` in `VerileriGoster`, plus some other fluff like selecting the filename to save with a SaveFileDialog

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I tried this, but "(ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage (saveFileDialog.FileName))" here "(saveFileDialog.Filename)" gives an error. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.FileInfo' gives an error.

Comment: One of the things I always forget is that EPPlus takes a FileInfo, not a string filepath. Simply change it like `new ExcelPackage (new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName))` and remember to `using System.IO`

Comment: This time it worked. I clicked the button and the file selection section came up. When I said save, I got another error. I think it's something about the EPPlus license. OfficeOpenXml.LicenseException
   HResult = 0x80131500
   Message = Please set the ExcelPackage.LicenseContext property. See https://epplussoftware.com/developers/licenseexception ... error like this. I tried something but couldn't. How do I fix it?

Comment: I installed an earlier version and it was fixed. Now everything is running smoothly and the way I want. Thank you for everything. :)

Comment: If you read that document, it basically says something like "read the license, if your use means you have to pay, then pay and set Licensed = true, if your use means you don't have to pay, then set Licensed=true".. What you do is up to you and your moral compass, but realistically, if youre using this software in a context that it should be paid for (commercial) it won't be your pocket funding it anyway. The developers have done an awesome job so they deserve the money (as does anyone who works in excahnge for money) so do pay if you ought to. Or you can use v4, which is licensed differently