# Export from DataGridView to Excel error Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export data from DataGridView to an Excel file, the DataGridView contains cells with Date and Int was working until I added 2 more columns (1 with text and 1 with Date).

Now I get the error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))'

This is my code:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet.Name = "Raport";

        for (int i = 1; i < tabinregrap.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = tabinregrap.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tabinregrap.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabinregrap.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tabinregrap.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        var saveFileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialoge.FileName = "output";
        saveFileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";

        if (saveFileDialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        }

        app.Quit();
```

Comment: With the posted code, I am unable to reproduce the error you describe. Are you sure the error is coming from the posted code? And if so… what line throws that error?

Comment: hi is not coming from a line the app is entering in break mode give theat error and when press continue the app close

Comment: As I previously commented, the posted code works as expected without errors. You stated you recently added some columns… take them out and see if the error goes away. I am just saying that the error does NOT appear to be coming from the posted code. From what I can tell adding more columns to the grid will make no difference. I did this and it still worked as expected without errors.

Comment: Bind your grid to a datatable. Write the datatable to an excel file using the technique here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus - you do not need excel installed, nor do you need interop which is the originating source of your error. No interop, no error

Comment: If open to using a free third party Excel library known as SpreadSheetLight I can post a solution which exports from a DataGridView to Excel and formats the date cells and has the ability to either write to a new sheet or to append to an existing sheet.

Comment: i found the problem it was Microsoft Office i had to install a new version

Comment: In regards to ` install a new version` this is one issue that can happen again which generally does not happen with libraries using Open XML such as EPPlus and SpreadSheetLight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem it was Microsoft Office i had to install a new version